# How to render text saperated by new line in HTML <li> tags?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working with AngularJS. I got a TextArea which is bound to say 'scope.listOptions' property.

This textarea is expected to contain multiple entries separated by new lines e.g.

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
```

For each row in textarea, i need to render it in HTML's <LI> tag like

Item 1

Item 2

Item 3

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: any code? what you did so far?

Comment: Its funny, I have no clue how to do this in AngularJs. In Js/jQuery, I know how to accomplish it.

Comment: @AnkurNigam what's wrong with my answer with working example? also, there is no rule that says you can't use jquery with angular

Comment: Code that you shared works fine but its doesn't follow the AngularJs approach.

Comment: @MaximShoustin Just a though, what if I split the content of textarea on ngKeypress event to JSON array and assign it to some property and using ng-Repeat, render the items. What is your take on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to break them into an array, then iterate over the array to print them out.

```
var items = scope.listOptions.split('\n');
for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++)
{
     output.innerHTML = output.innerHTML + "<li>" + items[i] + "</li>";
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/B6cNY/